# Why isn't a heatsink enough to cool a CPU?

Tags: heatsink, cpu-cooler

Why can't the heatsink alone cool a CPU? Why isn't carrying heat away from the CPU enough?
EDIT: Why can't heatsink with heatpipes cool a CPU?

Comment: Sometimes it is enough.  Depends if the CPU is designed to be passively cooled.

Comment: The premise of this question also seems to be focused on custom PCs. With that in mind you must realize the following: The vast majority of PC users nowadays do not custom build their PCs. For most people and off-the-shelf system is 100% fine and many of these systems use CPUs that do not have fans. The world of custom PCs is really about building speed-demons and people are obsessed with pushing the limits of CPU performance. So for a custom PC a heatsink alone *might* be good enough. But why build a custom PC? Get fans, get liquid cooling, go nuts! Custom PCs are like custom cars nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

Because just *moving* the heat is not enough. If you move the heat without trying to dissipate it (I.e. cooling the heatsink by using air to take the heat away) then all you are doing is heating up two things instead of one.

Imagine that you have a cup with a tap pouring water into it. That is your processor generating heat. It will fill quickly and overflow and everything will go wrong.

Now put that cup in a sink. (The heatsink) The sink is plugged. The water can overflow from the mug and fill up the sink without issue, but the overflow pipe on the sink can only take so much and it will fill up and eventually overflow and everything will go wrong again.

In order to stop the sink filling up you need to open the plug and actively remove water. This is effectively what the fan is doing, it is removing heat.

ARM processors are highly power efficient and their heat output can be handled simply by passive cooling and throttling to keep them below certain limits.

Intel processors tend to be capable of far higher power draws and can easily overcome heatsinks without active cooling. There are some passively cooled devices, but their performance is far more limited as a result.

It's all a factor of a figure known as TDP - Thermal Dissipation Power. This is the amount of heat that the processor generates (and uses) to do work.

Processors with lower TDP generate less heat and need less cooling. ARM processors tend to be <10 watts of heat, especially in phones or tablets. Intel laptop processors tend to be either 15, 25 or 35 watts of heat, desktop processors can easily go up to 95 watts or more for the ultra high end.

The whole point of a heatsink is to increase the surface area of processor so that you can effectively move heat away from it. You have only two options.

1. Bigger heatsink, more surface area to shed heat
2. Use a smaller heatsink and a fan to push cool air at it and shed heat

Fanless heatsinks for desktop style processors [tend to be *huge*](https://www.quietpc.com/orochi).

Answer (score 2):

Your premise is wrong.

Your mobile phone or the new Macbook Air don't have any active cooling. All the heat is radiated passively. Some desktop(ish) CPUs, like for example Intel's Celeron J4125, are designed to be cooled passively. Finally, [passive coolers for generic CPUs exist](https://www.arctic.de/en/Alpine-AM4-Passive/ACALP00022A).

But then, try passively cooling the aforementioned J4125 or some Athlon APU without an airflow. The heat will move from the CPU die to the radiator, but then it has to be dissipated into the air. As the air in the case gets warmer, the temperature difference between air and the radiator is smaller and this process becomes less efficient, so the radiator heats up. This makes the difference between CPU temperature and radiator temperature smaller too, so this heat transfer is also less efficient. You need airflow to move the hot air out of the case.

Same principle applies to active cooling, except the airflow is created directly on the heatsink to move more hot air out of it. If the CPU produces enough of heat, it will be a necessity - a heatsink alone won't suffice.

By the way, on the other end of the spectrum, rack servers typically don't have CPU fans despite having CPUs that are often more powerful than in desktops. Instead they have very powerful fans that create a lot of airflow in the entire case and cool the radiators. Desktop cases aren't fit for this style of cooling. The "cheese grater" Mac Pro uses it though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the manufacturer's specifications for your particular CPU.

In general, your statement is not completely true.

All of my computers now and back over time have been cooled just fine by the heat sink on the CPU.

This is also true of all customer machines as well.

You edited your question.  Of course, all our machines (my own, customers) have fans. All of them but I thought you were speaking of more advanced cooling. Fans have always been needed.

Comment: “This is also true of all customer machines as well.” What is a “customer machine?” Do you mean a “consumer machine?” Like a basic PC people buy to just have a PC and not a tweaker’s customized machine?

Comment: All our commercial customer machines (thousands over a couple of decades) need only the heat sink on the CPU and not a cooler on top of that. That is why I suggest the Author look at their own specs.

Comment: This is highly dependent on the type of machine bought and the selected processors. We've used passive cooled industrial machines, but they *do* have limitations and throttling that you need to be aware of.  I would assume anything without a fan is going to be at least half as performant as a machine with a fan. Your customers might well be happy with "slow but durable" fanless machines. Performance per watt has definitely improved over the years so they may well be acceptable.

Comment: I understood the question differently until is as edited. All our computers need fans. Always.

Comment: I understand now, but on modern PCs having a fan — or not having a fan — is really not an expected thing. For example, I have a MacBook Air (Intel, 2020) and there is a fan in the case but utterly none on the CPU at all. The MacBook Air (M1, 2020) has utterly no fan and outperforms my machine. I wish I could have that but I need to use VirtualBox so until that can be ported or rejiggered in some way for M1 CPUs I am stuck here. But many MiniPCs are rock solid, perform well and have no CPU fans. This is the modern world of PCs.

Answer (score 0):

A heat sink or heat spreader's job is to spread heat across a larger area. A larger area allows heat to dissipate more easily. For something like a smartphone, the thermal output is low enough that passive dissipation is enough. A CPU on a PC generates much more heat and would heat up the surrounding air faster very quickly. That's where a fan comes in, helping carry the heat away